# Image Data URI Active record Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord, uri

I am running an API Request in the Rails Console to return the data of a movie poster.

I start by specifying what the movie is so,

```
@movies = Movie.find('Iron Man')
```

It then returns the one of the posters' urls
http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/s2IG9qXfhJYxIttKyroYFBsHwzQ.jpg

I then run a code to return the above poster's data, this is what it gives

```
    > @movie.posters.first.data
 => "\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xFF\xDB\x00C\x00\x03\x02\x02\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x04\x03\x03\x04\x05\b\x05\x05\x04\x04\x05\n\a\a\x06\b\f\n\f\f\v\n\v\v\r\x0E\x12\x10\r\x0E\x11\x0E\v\v\x10\x16\x10\x11\x13\x14\x15\x15\x15\f\x0F\x17\x18\x16\x14\x18\x12\x14\x15\x14\xFF\xDB\x00C\x01\x03\x04\x04\x05\x04\x05\t\x05\x05\t\x14\r\v\r\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\x14\xFF\xC0\x00\x11\b\x00\x8A\x00\\\x03\x01\x11\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xFF\xC4\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x01\x04\x03\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\a\x04\x05\x06\b\x00\x03\t\x02\x01\xFF\xC4\x00<\x10\x00\x01\x03\x02\x05\x01\a\x02\x05\x01\x05\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x11\x00\x06\a\x12!1\b\x13\x14\"AQa2q\x15R\x81\x91\xA1\t\x16#b\xC1\xD1\x17$34Br\x82\xA2\xB1\xFF\xC4\x00\x1C\x01\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x02\x03\x04\x06\x01\a\b\xFF\xC4\x007\x11\x00\x01\x03\x03\x03\x01\x05\a\x03\x04\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x03\x04\x11!\x05\x121A\x13\"Qaq\x06\x14\x81\x91\xA1\xB1\xD12B\xC1#R\xF0\xF1\x15$b\x92\xA2\xE1\xFF\xDA\x00\f\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xE6\xEEV\x88\x95\xBA\x01\x1C\xDE\xF8\xD5\xC4\xD0\x02\x0FR\xE3d\x7F\xD1\xFC\x9C\xAC\xC5^\x8FLi!oMi\xF8\x8D\x8FR\xA5\xB2\xB0\x91\xFA\x92\x06\x02{E'c\xA5\xCF'\xF6\x8B\xFC\x88)\xDA1\x0E\xD4\"\a\xA9\xB7\xCC\x10\xAB\x86t\xA49G\xAC\xCAa\xD4\x94).\x90\x12G\xCE\x01R\xC8%\x8C8-5S\v\x1CA\xF1M\xD4f\x82\xEA\r\xF1{\x10m\x89f6aM\xA7\x03z\xB0:A\xA2U\x9DJ\xACJ\x8DN\x88\xB7\x9CDr\xFAR\x94\xF2@8\xC6\xD7\xEA,\xA5`.=V\x92\b7\x12J7\xF6\xFB\xD2Yz\x7F\x96t\x84xE7Og)1O.\xDB\x81!$-\xC4\x9Fbw_\xF7\xC5m\x182)% \xF7\xA4!\xE7\xD0\x8B\x03\xE9\x84r\x93eD\x124\xF2\xD2G\xC3\xFD\xAA+^\xA5?N\x10\x9DxY\x13\x19/\xB5\xF2\x8D\xEAE\xFF\x00t+\e\xF8_u\x84\xAF\x8Fc\xC1\xBF?\x9B\x7F\t\xB5\n\xDB\xD3\x95\x1E\x98\xBA\r\x90\xCB]\x12\xB4\xDF@3\xD6\xA78\xA6\xE8pR\x9D\xC2\xE3\xC4\xBC\e\xDF\xF6\x1D\x7F\x8CP\x96\xBE8N\xD2O\xC1_\x8BO\x9AV\xEE\x02\xC3\xCD*\xD4\x8D\x16\xD4M\x13r*\xF3\x8E[\x97\x0E$\x85\x94D\x9A,\xE3+]\xBA!\xC1qr?\xE968\xBFK\xA8\tM\x98n~\xA1R\xA8\xA2|\"\xEF\x16\x1FD\xD4\xEC5\xA62\x14\xEB]\xD3\xD6\xB2\x87\xBF\xC8\xC6\xA5\x80\xED\xBB\xB9Y\xFD\xC3u\x9B\xC2H\x12\xD5\xBF\xBC\xF2\xAB\xDA\xD7\xC5\x96\x90\x02q\xBFE\xBF+4Z}\x17\xB0=o\xD7\x14\xD8,\x13j]ud\xF4R\xBE\xEE_\xAFR\xAAp\x83F|)(\x92\xC2]\xE5\x05\xC4\x90R\x15\xF0H\x00\xFC`m|\"\xA2'D\xFE\x1C\b>\x85AJ\xF1\x14\xADx\xE8n\x96\xF6\x86\xEC\x81*\xBE\xD5s=@\xCF\xD96+hm\xD9\xD2\xE8\x13^v\rF3\xBC\xA9q\xFC:\xC2\xBC\xC0\xDD \x05\e\xF1\xE8o\x80\xB4\xDA$\x94\x11\x061\xDB\x988v,G\xAD\xD1\xE9\xB5\xB8\xAA\xDFg\xB7k\xFA\xB7$\xDF\xD2\xC3\xE6\xA9\xEES},\xD7\"\x97\x1Cj;Ei\xDC\xF3\xC8+Kb\xE2\xEA)\x1C\x9B{\fWtL\x96\xD1\xC8\xEB\x03\xC9\xF0D\xA3\x95\xF1\xDD\xECm\xCFA\xE2\xBA-\xA6\xDA\xE7\xA1\xFAi\x067\x85\xCC\x99\xABR+\xAE\xA05\xF8m*\x9E\x9A\x1C\x178\xB9C\x8A\x04\xB8\xA4\xDF\xA8+ \xFA\x83\x8A\xEF\xD2tZK\xC9;\xC1\xB6o\xDEy\xF8\f5Fj\xF5z\xC2\e\fv'\xC4\x86\x8F\x89\xEF\x13\xF0\b\xEB\xDA_Hb\x8E\xC8\x15\asUD=Y\x9B%\x12\xA9Q\x16\xB2[\xA5\xAD\xD5on\fM\xDEb\x94\x8B\xEER\x89$%G\xCA\x94\x803:\x85tu\xF3\xD3\xD6\xE9\xF1vq\xE0\x11\x81v\xD8\x8B\xBA\xD8\x1E6\x1DQ\xAD\n\x19\xE8\xA54\xF2?{\xCD\xC5\xF2rO\x9Em\xE1~\x8B\x8Du\xCA\xAB\xD3\xFC$wW\xBD\x10\x90\xA6\x1A?\xE0.)\x7F\xFDY\xFD\xF1\xAF\x8CX]\r\xAC\x93|\x9BOK\xFD\xD2\x18\x8E\xA9\xA7\xD0R\x017\x1D~\xF8\xB1|\x15@r\xAE\xF7f\xBDj\xC8\xDAn\xFD=Y\x8F0\xB1\x04\xABi.\xA1\xB7\x16\xA6\xBD,\xB2\x84\x9D\xBF\xAE3\xB2S\xC9#\xCB\x9A\x16\xA7\xDE\xA2c\x03\x1C\xEC\xAB{\xDA\x1F<\xE9~\xA8v~\xAB\xC1{:QW\x1A\xAF\x05\xC7\xA9NH\x92\x84w\xAF\xB5u6\xB6\xC9\xEA\xA0\xE2@\xE3\xDC\x8Fq\x86S\xF6\x8C\xA8k\x9A\r\xC1Q\xD4\x18\xDD\x03\x83\x88\xB1\x18\\\xC5\xAFBS\x8D\xA5\xC0\x8B)I\v)\xFB\x8B\xDB\x1E\xB5\x10\xDE\x17\x97\xB5\xDB]e\x19\xF0\xEB\x04\xF1o\xFCq1\x8E\xCA\xDE\xE0W\x9C\xB5()\xA4\x8By\x87\x1Dz\xE0{\r\xC2\xEDCH(\xB5\x91\xEA*ah\xF3\x10\x0F\x04\xDF\r\x90\x02\x10\xFC\x87aO;cj+\x1A\x86\xBA\x15]\xE6\xBB\xA9_\x84GbC\x97\xE5\xC7\x10\vd\x9F\x90\x7F\x82\x9Cy,43\xD1\xD7L\xD7\x9B\xB5\xCE\xBB}9\x1F\x8F\x82\xF4\xC8\xAAb\xA8\xA2\x8C\xB7\x90,}\x7F\xCC\xAAo\x04\xEC\x94\x80z%v8\xD3\xBC]\xA8tG\xBC\x8E\xBA-\x06\x04<\xD9\x1Al\xE7\x10\xC4\x16\\C\x8E8\xBE\x89\x17\e\xBF\xF5\n\xC63Vt\x92@bg\xEA7\v[B\xD61\xFB\xDD\xC2\xB2\xFA\xD7\xAFs\xFBB\xD6s\x1Du\xF7\xD5I\xCBYV\x99\xDCR\xA0\xADvJ$I\xF2 \x11\xD0\xBAZK\x8BQ\xF4\x05)\x1C\x03z\xF4\xB1I\r$m\x96\xD7\xC0\xB0\xE3\x1C\x9F\xC2\xD1\xFB3J\xC7\xEA\x0F\x97\xA3\x1A\xE7\x12\x7F\xB8\x83\xB4\x7F\x9E+\x9EU\x88nC\x98B\xC6\xDD\xFEp>.\x7F\xD3\e\xC8\x9D\xB9\xA1y\xA5|&\x1A\x87\x03\xD7)3D\a\x12U\xF4\x82/\x89\xFA!\xE1t\e\xB2\xCE\x82\xE9\x85z\x83+2L(v\x02\xE1\x97jt\x8A\xA3M\xBA\xD6\xD6\xC1p\xAD.\x11\xBD\xB1\xC5\xC9I\x1E\xDE\xD8\x05$\xF2\xB4\xEC<\xAD\eib\x00<\f\x1F\x150\xD3j6\x8Cv\x8A\xD2\a\xF2\xFCF\xE9H\xCC9\\I\xF0hN\xFF\x00\x13\n\b\x90_l\xB4\xBE7#r\xC2J\xF9<\xED8k]4\x0F\xBB\xB86Ms`\x9D\x9B[\xD0 l\xED'\x99>\x8E\xF4\xF4$\x06\x9BN\xE2zz^\xC0~\xFF\x00\xB6=F\x9Ef\x80\x1A\xBC\x8ER\xE0\xE2B\b\xD5\a\x83\x9A\xE3JI\n\a\x9E1q\xE4_\b\xA4Cs\x01\xBA\x88P\x1D6\x01&\xD7\xEA/\x81\x11\e\x84Fq\x94N\xCB\xB3\x14\x84\xB7\xB5W\xF9\xBFLLE\xD0g\f\xA2:r\xA4=S\xA41\x97\xA5>\xDC\x17\xDF%\xB8\xB3]6CO(\x10\x82\xB3\xF9\n\x8AB\xBE\r\xFD1\x99\xD5\xEF\f&\xA46\xFB3a\xCD\xBA\xDB\xD3\x95\xA2\xD1^\x1F#\xA9\x89\xB6\xF1\x83\xE62\a\xC4\\z\xD9UWa;O\x9A\xF4yI\xEEd2\xB56\xE27\x03e$\x90z{\x10F(\\8\x02\xDE\n.\xC2\x01\xB9VK\xB2\x8D3\"f\xBA\xF4\xD4j\x0Ekc(\xE5\x98\x88\x12\x1E\x99)\xA76I(IY\x8E\x95\x84\x90\x16\xA4\xA4\x90\x93\xCA\x80! \x9E1\x91\xD5i\xAA\xDF\xB5\xB4\xB6\x0E7\xC9\xCD\xBC\xEC2~\xC3\xA9\b\xF5=\\Q\xC6\xE7<\x13ka\x10\xB3\xD6_\x01\xA8\xF9.\x9BG\xA9R\xDD\xCD5\x95\xE6\xA9N\xD4\x18\f\xF8J|\x87vD.\x80\xA2\x13\xB5\x92\x8F%\xEE\t\xB7\x04\xE2:h\x9C\xFD\xAD\xDC\x1C#\x01\x97\a\x92\x06O\xC4\xAD\xF6\x95\xA8\xD2i\xF4\x0Eu\xEF,\xA4\x928\xB6z\x9F!a\x85K3]I\x15|\xC5>[7\xF0\xCE<\xAE\xE1%!;Z\x06\xC8\x16\x1D<\xB6\xC6\xD6&\x0607\xC1y-d\xEF\xAA\x9D\xD3\xBF\x97\x14\xD2o\xCE%T\x91\xCBEu\x830\xE5\xEAt\xDAE\f\xA9\x12&\xB4\x98\xF2\x1D\x10\xCC\xB3\xDD_\x94\xA5\xB0\b%]\r\xC7LP\x96&n\xDE\xF4^*\x87\xC9\x1Fd\xCC\x1F\x1EQ\xCBC\xA6H\xC94\x8A\xEBYu\x99\xB4\xE4I\x1E\n\xAE\xD5B\x94\xA8\x82M\xF7m(**\xF3\xB6U\xE8R,z\x1E\x82v\xB1\xB3\xCB\e_\xEA,\xAA\xCA\xF1M\f\x8E\x8C\x90@\xCD\xFC\xF0\x8CZ\x9D\"&H\xD1\x9A]1-7\xF8\xA5Dx\xE7]?[,\x91\xB5\xA4|n\xE5G\xE3n4\xB0\x13$\xC5\xDD\x06\x16\x12F\x81\x10m\xB2s\xF8\xFC\xAA\x15\x99\x9FS\x95w\x94\x14y\xF6\xC1\xB7X\x9C\xAB\x906\xCC\n\x15Gwk\x83\xD0t8\x13\tE&\x18DZ\x04\xE4\x84\x04\x8B\x03\xB7\xAD\xF1m\x04\x90\x10T\xEE\x89\x9B\xD7Au\x89Q\xD4\x85=\x1D\xC4\xBA\x80\xE1\xE3rHP\xB8\xFD9\xF8\xC42D%\x05\xA7\x82\x9A\xC2XA\x1C\x846\xD7\xEC\xC7I\xCD\x1A\xAFY\xAEe\xEAji4\xCA\x82\x19SpR\x00K\x044\x84\xA9\t\x03\xA2n\x9E>-\x8C5%5E,]\x85S\xB79\xA4\xE7\xC4\\\x90~D-\xFC\xEE\x84\xF6r\xC0p\xF6\x83o\x03\xC1\x1F0\x9C4\x8B_\xEB\x1AQH\xACR\xE1D\x84\xEC*\xA4\x98\xD2\xA4&K\tz\xEAgv\xC1\xB5wA\x17Y6RM\x88\x04\x11l\x0F\xD44\xB6\xD6\xBD\x92\x17\x10Z\b\x166\xE7\x94B\x8A\xAA(\xC3\x9B(\xE6\xDD.\x91j\x16\xB0g|\xD3\xF8\x95VeFjb\xD7\x1D*u\xE4\xAD[]\t&\xCD\x95\xFA\xD8\x92m\xEEon\x05\xADP\xD1AG\x18\x86!k}\xFCS+\xE7\x99\xED\xDF\xFB]\xC7\xA2\x14\xDE\xF6\xC1\x81\x85\x9F\xE5[\xDE\xCD}\x94\xA8\xBA\xBF\x92\x1E\x9DQ\x8A\xE8^\xE2\x92\xFBN)+A\xB7\x04z~\xE0\xE0\rUl\xB1I\xDC\xE1i)\xA8\xA1|@<d\xA0^\xA3eZ\xEFg\x8DT\xAAQ`\xD5d\xC6\x91\x14\x82\xC4\xD8\xEB-)\xD6V7$\x9B\x1E\xB66? \xE0\xBD3\xD9U\x18y\x1C\xF4Ag\x8D\xD4\xB2\x96\x02\xAD\x86\x86\xE9\xC5z\x8D\x912\xADg6W\xA4\x05\xE6I\x0EJ4g\xAE{\x8A{\b*/\xAC\x92|\xCA+\x01\"\xC3\xEA\xF5=4qS1\xA0\x9D\xBD\xE0>\xA7\xA7\xE5e\xABj\x89\x01\x81\xD8'\xEC\x9D5\x92\xA9'5\xB9*xRP\xDB\xC2\xE9a\\\x04\xA0yR\x91\x7FD\x80\a\x1E\xD8\xB5\ff!b\x10\xE7\xB8;\xAA\xAA\xB5\xBA\x02\xCDI\xDB$\xDB\x8E\xA7\x16\xF7\x8E\xAAfH@\xB2\x17At\xA5d\x03k\x8B_\x03\"6Z\x17\x8B\xA9D\x1A\xA2X\xB2\x94\x02S`-\xEB\x8B\xA1\xC8[\xE2'\x85\xEAff\tmM\xA4\x90:\xF0p\x8B\xC3Re1&\xE9\x1D\r\x0FW\xEBq\x18\xF0_\x88%\xD5\xA5\r\xC7Q$8\xB2xO\x04\x1El@\x17\xB9\xBF\x18\xCEW\xD4\xF6\x8D;N\x02\xD5i\x14\xC0\xD5G\e\xD9\xBBq\xB5\xBC~Y\xCA\xD3^\xCB5\x1AMN\xA2\xDC\x98I\x80\xFA\x1Dq\v\x8E\xE1\t[E+)Zv\xDE\xE0\x82-n\xBC`[^6\x8B\x94Zzg\x19e0\xB4\x01\x7F\x97\x90=S<\xE7e5\t\x10\x16\xF2\x93\x1D\xB7\v\xC8\x8E\xA5\e]@y\x88\xBD\xB7X\x01\xEF\xC6,4\x87\v\x84\nh\xA4\x89\xDBd\xC1\xE6\xDE\xA9\x13IJ\x90.\xAD\xA4(s\xF1\x89:(:\xAE\x9CvG\xCF\xD9W+\xE4\xA57'9Qc\xC7,\x03\xFD\xE3\xC9m[\x82E\xD1\xB4\xF2U\x7F@\t\xE7\x19i\xE2\x90\xBC\x80\xD2\xB61L\xCD\x8Du\xC6\x10\xBF\xB6\x1E\x9D\xCA^\xAE\xE4\xAC\xE1L\x10\xAAO\xD6Jb\xA2\x14\xE8\xE4\xC6RZ\tXZ\x95\xEBp\xE8\xE1\"\xE9\t\xF76\xC6\x87\xD9\xE0\xF2\x1C\xC6\xFE\xDC\x9B\xF9\xFF\x00\xA5\x9D\xD7\xB64\t\x1EM\x9D\x8Cy\x7F\xB4\xE9\x98\xF5>]r\x9D'2\xCB\xA7\xF7*Zc\xD3\xA2S#,\xBA\x86b\xB4N\xE2\x95\x00<\xAA^\xE5\xDE\xC2\xF7M\xF1\xE8\x90\xD3\x86\x90\xCB\xF9\x93\xE6W\x98O.\xF7\xF7z`]0\xD63I\xCC\xB9.}Uq\xCB\x1D\xF4\x87P\x86;\xBD\xA9i\xB4\xD8!)\xF8\xDBc\x7FRI\xF5\xC7$\x8F\xB3xkN,\xA4\x04\x91\x9EUd\xAB\xD6^f\xA0\xF2[yhE\xF8\x01d\f5\xD8<#1F\v\x01\xB2\x1F\xB6\xBD\xB6\xB7Q\x8C\xE3J>BS\xE2\xD4\e\xDB\xB8\xDB\xE7\x13\xF6\x98\xB5\xD4{\x05\xEE\xB67\x01\xD7\xA2\xAAB\xEE\x11p\x94\x0F\xCCOL\a\xA8\xA9\xBB\xBB6\xFCQ\xAAz\a:\x03P\xEE/a\xE6S\xFC9\xA9\xA3S\xA3\"1\x02bJ\xDC.\x8E\vEV\x1D\x7F6\xD4\xF5\xF4\xDC@\xC52\xE0[\xB4\x05~\ngD\xF1+\x8D\xAD\xC7C\xEAJH\xB2\xDBR[r[\xC8SE!\xC5-*\xDCH#v\xDF\xFB\xBD>\xE7\x15\xCB\\\r\x87*\xF4R\xC0v\xBECf\x0F\xA8\x1D\a\xAD\xAD\xF1Q\xC9\xB2\x95.B\xDE_\xD4\xE1*?\x1C\xF4\xC5\xB6\xB44X,\xC4\xF3:\xA2WJ\xFEI\xBA\xF0\xCB\x81\xB5\xA4\xA9!i\x04\x12\x93\xD0\xDB\xD3\x0F\xB5\xC2\xAE9\xBA\xBD=\x89\xB5*\x8D\x97r4\xF3'.\xB0\x89,V\xCC\xA6gI\x8CJ\x18m\xE0\x86\xB6\xC7u \xA9\v\x05)\xB9W\x90\x8E\x0FP@\x8A\xA8\x1E\xF7\r\xA7\x90\x8D\xD2\xCC\xC60\x977\x17\xF8'N\xD1\xF5\x8A\xBEd\xD76\xE0\xB1%\xFA\x92it\xF4\xA5\x96\x90\x90;\xB7\x9El8\xFA\xAC:(\xA7\xBA\x1E\xC2\xC0zcQ\xA5G\x1E\x9B\xA6\xBA\xA6Q\xCF>y\xB0\x1F5\x99\xD4\xE4\x93S\xACm4G\xFC\xEAS\xC4|\xB4\xEC\x1At\x14L\x8C\xE4\x12\xEB+\x02;\xED\x80B\x10\xB2\xDF\x02\xFF\x00O\xA8\xE9pol^\xD35\xA6j/{\x03v\xB9\xB9\xE6\xF8B\xB5-\nM9\xADyv\xE0q\xC7T?\xD4\x1A\xF4\xE9Q*\x11\x1F\x84\xA8t\xC8i\xEEc\xA8\x9F+\xA9\a\xC9ok$^\xDF\xE28\xD2\xC5\x17\xEE\xBD\xC9Y\xE2\xEB\x90\xD2\xAAmfF\xEA\x9C\x83\xE9\xB8\xDB\x15\xA6=\xF5\xAC\x85\xBD\xC0\xA3\xA0\xDB\x19PQ%\xB6\x1CuM\x96\xCCtr\xB7V\x10\x00\xF98\x8AI64\xB8\xF4Vi\xA0uL\xCC\x85\xBC\xB8\x81\xF3*mU\xA2;\x1A\x1C\x14\xA1 7b\xBB$rU\xD0\x13\xF6\x18\xCE\xB2P\xE7\xB8\xBB\x95\xE9\xF5\x9AS\xA1\xA7\xA7dc\xBA.}\\x?\x00\x9BSMz2\xD0RU\xDF\x02\bROC\xF1\x89;at0\xE9\xCFh\xB1\xC9)\x92\xB6\x16\xCB\xFD\xD2\x88U\xBD\xBE}qj#\xB8nY]D\x18\x9F\xD9t\t\xAC\xE2t\x1Dm\x8D\xC3\xC8'\xA5\xFAbX\xBFX\xBA\xE1\xE1\\\x1E\xC42\xE3W\xB33\xB4\xC9\xCBb\x99Jx\xED_x\xA1g\xDCH+\xDA\x94\xF5\xDER\x95[\xA0\xE3\xDF\x83vJ@\xF6\t\x9A8*\xA9\xA8tg\xB2'\x05NP\xFDk:U\xB5+R\x19\xA1\xCD\xA9SK\xABe,C\x8E\\!\x83\xFD\xDA\x12H \xA4lJ.G&\xE6\xDDp\xCDn\xA28)\xE1\xA1i\xCF'\xCB\x18\xBF\xA9\xE3\xD1I\xA3S\xBEi\xA4\xAC-\xC0\x16\x1Ef\xF9\xB7\xC1/\xD4\f\xE3\x02$\xEA}\x1E4\x05S\xEBT\xFAtV*\xE5]\xE8q\xC9+e\n>W\x14JR\x90\x12\b\x00\x1D\xC4\xDE\xF8\x17\xA1m\x8Ei\x1D\xD4\x8F\xE5\x18\xD7C\x9D\x04c\xA5\xCF\xD9\r3\xDB\xCF\xCB\xA7\xA6\xC0:\x9E\x8A\bQ;O\xCF\xB7\xA7\xEE1\xE9t\x92\x89\x06\x17\x99T@b\x90\x17*\xE3]\xA4\xED\xAA=\xC7S~\xB8\xEC\xB0\x878\x92\x16\x82\t\x7F\xA6\x14A \x9B\x01\xC9\xC6)\xAD\xBA2\xA7\xFA3\x93\xE5\xE6<\xF5\x05\r\xC6[\xE9a+\x90R\x94\xDE\xFBG\x03\xF7#\x1456>:W\x109\xC2\xD7{\"!~\xAF\e\xA56\f\xBB\xB3\xE41\xF5\xB2\xB5Ze\xD9O2jM\x1E\n\xA3\xD3K\xB5\x04G\xF3\xC5u\xC0\x85\r\xB6\xDF`y;I\x00\xFC\x91\xEF\x8CC\xE5\x91\xF3=\x90\x8B\x8B\xAFy\x8Am*\x8E\x8A\x9D\xDA\x94\x96yh\xC76?\x95\x01\xED5\xA3u\r\am\x86+\x10\xFC\rQ\xF6\xD2Xl\e\xDD&\xF7?\xA0\x1C\xFE\x98\xB3J%t\xDD\x9C\x82\xDDP\x9D~\xAFM\xFF\x00\x8B5\xFA{\xB7\x12v\x0F^O\xC8*\xB10\xA9J\xEF\x14|\xCA\xE6\xDE\xD8\xD47\x18\v\xE7\xC9\xEE\xE3\xBD\xDC\x94\x98\xF9\x96O\xB9\xBE\x1E\x15Eb{?\xE9\x8EB\xAD\x96\xE5gY\r\xB1\x19\xB4\xA9\xD7\x83\xB3T\xD9\t\x04\x02\xAD\xA8\xE4\x00H\xEA}p6\xA2\xA2X\xDF\xB5\x9Fdf\x9E\x96\x19\"\xDD'>\xA8\xE5\xFE\xC9\xA8\xD9\x17R(\x8Dd\xFA\xCA#e\xEA\xE8\xEE\xDC\x94\xA5\x17\xC4v\xD4\x9B\x87\x10\xA3\xE67M\xEC\x0F7\xB7=q{N\xD5\xA4k$d\xE2\xFBE\xC7\x9A\xA3\xA8i,q\x88\xC3\x80\xE3c\xD6\xC9\xA3R5\xE6.C\xAA\xD0\xE9\x94X\xD2#\xE4(2C\xB1b)jK\x93\xCA-\xDE:\xE9E\xB7)~\x97 \x01kq\x86\xBBO\xAA\xADw\xBC\xCE-\xBF\xE8\x15\x86\xD6\xD3Q\xB4\xD3S\xE7f>i]gVrGhL\xE3\x1ERY\xA9e\xAA\xDDI\x86`\xC8L\xB8\xC9Z%\xBA\x9B\x86\xDF\x0E6n\x16R\x9D\xAA\x04sd\x9B\x8B`\x8B4\xCFp\xED*X\xEB\x800\b\xB17<rG\xA2\x1C5'\xD7\x18\xA9f`\x04\xBB$\e\xDA\xC3\x9E\x01\xF5Qz\xCE\\\xADG\xABD\xA3Di\xC9h\x85\t\xC9N\xC4Jv]$\xABr\x8FP\x15\xB0$\xD8\x91\xF4\xD8X\x8B\x92Zv\xA3\v[\xDA\xC8\xE0\x0E\xED\xB9\xEA\xA2\xD4\xB4\xA9\x8B\xBB(\xDA\\6\xEE\xC7D\x16\xCC\x90\xD1\x16\xAC\xEBo\x8E\xE5V\n\tP\xB5\xC1\xE4\x11\xEE9\xEB\x8D\x98|re\xA6\xEB2\xC6=\x8D\x01\xC3*\x05\x97\xA8\xC9\x9F-\b\xEF\x80$\xFERF2t\xF0\xDD\xC1\x1A\x9E]\x8D7]B\xFE\x98\x9A\t\x06\xA1^\xAAf\n\x9CF\xE4\xB1\x19\x80\xDBd\x8B\x82\xA2A\xE7\xF6\x183\xAB\x86Q\xD21\xA0w\xDC~\x8B)\xA6\xCF-~\xA0\xFB\x1F\xE9\xB0[\a\x93tx\xD6\xAC\xE5J\xEC\xE1\xAE\x99J\xAE!\x94Q\xF7KT\x96\xE3\xA4\x05\x14\xBC\xC2\x81Jz\x0F\xA9\xB6\x8F\xDD8\xF2\xDA\xBF\xFAy\x85CF\b\xCF\xAD\xED\xFC\xAFv\xD0\xA8]\xAE\xD2\xBA\x84\xC9g\xB4\xD9\xA4\xF0\x05\xAF\x9F\xFCW0\xFBgv\x84\xA8v\x82\xD4\xBA\x8D~f\xD6b0\x9F\v\n*\r\xD2\xCBc\xD0\x1FS\xEE}M\xF1\xCAv\xB9\xEE\xED\x1E2~\x83\xA0F5\x9Fw\xD3\xA9=\xC2\x94\xDD\xB1\x82/\xFD\xCE?\xA8\xFF\x00\x03\xC0\x05Yd\xAC\xA9@z\x01\x82\xA0Yy\x8C\xAE\xDCV\xB4yH=9\xC3\x82\x85Xn\xCB9\xE2%:\xBBP\xA2\xD6\x18\xA7I\xA2V`\x1A}A\xD9\xF1\xDEt\xB0\xC2\x9EJ\xD6Q\xDDr\x92JB\xAFc}\x80p0*\xB6# \xB86 \xDF\b\xE6\x9D \x04\xB4\x8B\xE1\x17u36Qh3\xD3A\xC9\x91\xA1S\x11\x1A#\x8E\xAA\xA6\xD9R\xEE\xAB\x03\xDE\xA8\xAB\x9EGN/\xCF\xBE\x19E\x14\x92\xBE\xEE\xC98N\xD4&d-hf-\x94\x1E\xCEB^l\xCBj\\h\xD2%\xC8K\x89u\ta\x05E\xB7\a\xD5\xC0\xE8,I\xBFKc\xD2\x19]\x19\xA6\xDB1\xDA\xE6\xD8\x1F\x1F\v\xFCV\x05\xB4r2\xB3t\"\xEC}\xCE8\xB76\xF8\x14\x9B\xB3\x8DI\xDC\xAF\xAA\x91\x9A}\xAF\xF7\x96[|\xECX\ak\x856\xB8\xF9\xB5\xFD}qNX\xD9,\x05\xAD\xE0\xE5\x10/0\xCA\xD9:\x8C+\x14\xF6gv}v\xB1V5t\xD2\xDC\\_\n\x14Sp\xA5n\xB9Q\x03\xEA\xE3\x80H6\xE7\xD0\xE3!QA\xB1\x8C\x8C\xB2\xE0:\xF7\xFE\x16\xBA\x9BS\x0Es\xA4k\xB2@\x16\xF4\xEB\xE6|<\x1079G\xA77Se\x96\xD8\x8D%\xB6XKiq\xD4\x82\xA2.M\xF9\xFB\xDF\xF5\xC6\xAE\x9D\x929\x9B\x9CrVR\xA6a\xBE\xCD\xE0`!\xAE\x9D\xC3i\xDA\x9B!IR\xD4O\t\x06\xD8\x96\x9EG6F\xE1\v\xAEq\xEC\xDC\xBA\xF9\xFD:\xEB\xF4\xFAm\"},\xBA\x94Hs\x95$\x9E~0o\xDA(\xDD,\x11\xC8\xDE\x02\xC5\xFB-;b\xAB\x9E'\x9C\xBB(U\xFDR\xF3\x93+\xCC\xF4\x98l8\x92\xB8\xEC\xDF\xCA}\xD2\xAE\x7F\x9Cy\xE5DW\f\x0E\xF3\xFB\xAF\xA0\xBD\x9A\x98\xC4\xF9%i\xEA>\xC7\xF2\xB9oUjE^p\x89\x19\nu\xE7\x14U\xB6\xFD\x00\xE4\x92O\x00\x01\xC9'\x801\xD6\x80\xDC\xAAZ\x8C\xCE\x99\xDD\x98\xE4\x9B\xA8\xFC\x96\xD0\xC3\x85\xB4\xAC:A\xE5\xC4\xFD'\xED\xFE\xB8p\xB9\xCA\x06\xF0\x1Al2\xB4\xE1\xCA5!\xC8\xF5\xB9\x94*\xFB\x0F@\x82\xCDJS\x97i\x11\x9Fl\xAC(\x9E\x84X\x8B\x11\xE8}1\xCE\xC7\xB7\xEE\x0EJ\x91\x93v\a\x7F\xDD\x12W\x99cQf\xD4b\xD5T\xCE`\xAETX,\xCAm\x95\xA90\xE9\xA0\x90l\x14\x82\v\xAE\xA4\x81\xEA\x10\x9B[\xCEz\x1A\xD3i#\x8EM\xA7\xA76C\xEA\xE7|\xED\xED\x0F\xC1Gs\x06l\xACe\xC8QX\x839Q\x14\xF0QS\xB1^I+o\xD0*\xC6\xE2\xFDll~1gQ\x8D\xAE\xDB\xB8duP\xD1o\x8Fv\xD7`\xF4Hr]jT,\xCB\x1A\xA8\xFC\x82\xE9S\x9B\x96\xBE\xAA$\x82?\xCF\x13\xD2\xC4X\xDB_\n:\xBBH\b\xEA\x9D\xEB\xB9\x9EK2\x1CS\x12\\\xE6\xF6\e\xB8\xE7\x04\x9E\xC8\xC8\xEF*t\xE0\x80\xA1\xD33\x14\xB7^%O\xAA\xF6\xB6\a\xBEa\x19\xDA\x116\xC2\xD28K2\xF5qt\xC9(}\xA5\xEDP\xC58e-!\xEC6!A<\"F\x96\xB8a\x1D\xF4\x9F\xB4\x85SO\xEBlH\x831\xC6]X!J\n\xB76\xE3\xF9\xC1Q\xA9\xBD\x94\xEEc\x80p\xF3@\xA9}\x9D\x86\xAE\xBD\x84\xB8\xB2\xF8\xB8\xE53k\xB6\xAF\xD5\xF5*\xBE\xCDB\xB1(\xBD%m\x8D\xEBY\xE0\\\x9E\xBE\xDDq\x8E\x9AN\xDEG?\xE4\x17\xB1\xB6\x99\x9AU<P6\xF8\x19?\x94\x1A\xABW\x19\x8F\x11\xC8\x10\xAF\xB5\xCF\xF9\x99\x00X\xC8WP>\e\a\xA2}m\xB8\xF3`!-$\xDDg\xDF3{\xD7\xC9*6I&\xE7\xD7\x0FT\t\xBEW\xCB\xE3\x8B\x89\xD3.\xAEB*#\xC3\xC8\x11\x14\xA4)%\xF2\t\xD8\x9Brx\x04\x8Fk\x8F|_\xA5\xDE\x1D\xDC\xE4\xE1E k\x87{\x85\xB0\xD4\x8D5*j2\x82V~\xB5\xA7\xDF\xD8`\xBBj\x05\#{8\xF9\xEA\xAB\x98\x84\xC7s\xF8\xE8\x9B\xE4I[\xE6\xEBYs\xE4\xFA`|\xB5\x05\xE6\xD7\xBA\xB0\xD6\x06\xF0\x12\x8AuEP\xDFB\xAEJA\xBD\xB1b\n\xAD\xA6\xC5E,A\xE19?SD\xB2\b\x16\xFB\xE0\xB0\x94?*\xA8\x88\xB57\xC8h-\xD2G\xAE!{C\x8D\xD5\x96\x93d\x91\x0E\x14\x9E.0\f\x16\x9F\xD4\x14\xE4](nIh\x85)D\x01\xC8\x1E\xA7\x16\v\xC3E\x93\x03sq\xCA\x94J\xA8\xB5U\xA3Fx\xA8\x99*IK\xDC\xF4P\xE3\xA7\xB1\x16\xC6i\xE1\xCC\x94\x8E\x8B\xD0\xC5Du\x94,.\xFDV\xB1\xF5\x1F\x9C(\xC4\xA56\xCB\x83\xB8J/\xD3s\x8A\vW\xDF\xD8b\xC3M\xF2V6f\x86\e\x04\x89\xC5)j\xBA\x94V\xA3\xEAq\"\xAA\xB5\x80V\xB0\a$\x9B\f7\x93\x84\x94\xF2\x99\x06\x8F\x16\x96\xA5=\xE1\xDA\x92\x86\x8A\x94\xB7\x1DR\x94\xBB\x03\xC6\xD1\xC0\xB9)\xFE>pT40_\x83\xFEq\xEA\xABou\xEDk\xA85\xF9\xE7\x15\xB7\e\xE5X\xB2\xF8O8\x85\xCF\xCA\xEA\xF3\xBB\x11\x87\x90\x92\xF6\x87\x8Aqf:\x873\v\x84]l\xEF\xFD\xCE/{\xDF\x8Af\xD5\xAFz\xBF1\xFD\xF00H\xE1\xD5>\xCB\xE5\xCF\xBE9\xB8\xAE\xA5\xB0j\t\x8C\xCA\xDBZJ\x81;\x85\xBD\x0E\x19$e\xE4\x14F\x96\xA8@\xD71\xC2\xE0\xA4\xAF\xAD.:\xA5$\x10\x0F\xBE\x1E\xD6\x90,\xA9\xCA\xE0\xF7\x97\x05\xAF\x0E\x00\x81\xC2\x89g8V\xF2I}\xC3\xEC\x12_0\xDC\xA4\xB3\x9Cs>\t,=0\xD7q\xC2K\xCE!If\x12K\xED\xCE\x15\xD2R\x9C\xD1\x91$ex\xF4\xB7\\\x92\x87\xFCz\x94\x94\xA5()\xDA@l\x9F\xBF\xFCA\xFBb\xBC5\x02R\xEB\x0E?\xFB\xF8S\xBE'0\v\xF5RZ\xAE\x85\xD4i\xB4\xD7\xE6\n\x94WP\xDCg\xE5\x01\xB5@\xAD,\x82V=l|\xAA\x02\xE0\\\x8C1\x9A\x83^@\xB7\x87\xD5=\xF4\xE5\x82\xF7M\x993J&g*,\x8A\xA3S\xE2\xC4\x8C\xCA\xD4\x82\x1D$\xAC\x94\xED\xBF\x1F%i\x00^\xE4\x9E\x98\x96Z\xC1\x13\xB6[)\xAC\x84\xBD\xBB\xAE\x92'M\xE67\x9F\x8EV\x93)\x96d\x04\a\f\x80\x14\xA4\x04\x16C\xA0\xDB\xAF\xD2G\xEAq\xD3X;\x1E\xD8\x0F\xF2\xF6\\l%\xD2vkns\xD3)Y6\x96\x89\xAFKnB\x14\xF8f\xC8l\x8F\xA8(\xA4\xDC\xFB\x84\xDF\xF5\xC3 \xADl\xEF\xD8\x05\xB1u$\xB4\xCE\x89\xBB\xCA\xD1\x95t\xF5\xFC\xD7D\x9D:4\xA4\xA1\xF8\xEAR[\x8A[$\xBC\xA0\x8D\xDBA\x1C\x02z\v\xE2I\xAA\xDB\v\xC3]\xD568\x1D+K\x9B\xD1$\xCD\xB9*^QD?\x12\xB0\xB5\xC8\xDC6\x84\x91\xB5I\xDBq\xF3\xF5\x7F\x18\xECUM\x9A\xE5\xBD\x13e\x85\xD1[r}\xACh\xD5b\x8BN~S\xCE\xB0\xAE\xE5Km\xC4\xA2\xE6\xCBBJ\x94\x9F~\x80\xF3k\e\x1CB\xCA\xF6Hl\x13\x9FN\xF6r\xB4\xE4],\x7F<\xC3\x86\xFB5\x16b\x99\x15\x11O\r\xAD\xB5(\xA6\xE9B\xB7\xF1\xE9\xE7\xE9\xD7\x8C*\x8A\xC6\xC3p\xE1\xD2\xEB\x91B\xE9xL\x19\xC3+/)U\x11\ro\xF8\x8D\xEC\xA1\xE0\xBD\x9B8U\xF8\xB5\xCF\xB6\x1D\f\xA2V\xDC&I\x19\x8C\xD8\xA6<N\xA2X:\xE1$\xAC\xF7iL\xA0\xDE_\xA5iJ\xD1{Nu\xF5n#\xA8\xDB\x0F\x9F\xE4\xE3'\xA4N&mC\x81\xE0\xDB\xEE\xB4Z\x936:\x01k\\\x02\x8E\xD9\xD7JX\xA7i\xBE|\x9D\xB9e\xF8\x99~\xA0\xFAw\xA3\xCA\x84\xAB\xBF\x00\x0Ey\xB8J\xF9=\n\x87[c=A\xA8\t*\xA9\xE3\xE7y?\xFA\x84b\xBE\x902\t\x9Do\xD3o\xAA\x80\xF6C\xD3\a\xF3\x96\x95\xBD%\f)\xD4?S\\1\xB1\xB2\xAB\x12\xECRI qas\xF6\xC4\xDE\xD0\xEA\xD1\xD0\xD5\x16Hm\xDC\xBEO\xAA\x83J\xA3\xED\xA9D\x9F\xF7[\xE1\x84\xD7;\"\xAAGo\xE9\xD9M\xB6\n\xCE\xDF\a\xDD\x00o\xE5\xA6'\xD3\xF4\xC5\xB9\xF5\x10=\x9Cmq6\x16i\xF9\xB8*\xB4\xB1\xC6\xED\\\xB3\xF6\xDD\xDFb\xA7}\xBF\xF4Q\x9D2\xD1\\\xB5Qd\xF7\x9E*\xB8\x88\xE5\xD0\x9D\xB7\xDB\x1D\xDE\b\xF8)#\xF48\x05\xEC\x96\xA8\xFA\xFDBV8\x10\x1A\xDB\xFC\xC8W5\xB9!4\xEDd|\xEE\xFE\n\x13vb\xA6FgJ\xF3.c\x99\nD\xD84Y\x8B\x9711\x80\xEF\x12\xCAXAQI<n\x02\xE4\\\x80H\xF4\xC6\x97Y\x986\xB6\x18\v\xACd\xC0\xF5%S\xD2{\xB4\xD3\xCBo\xD3b\xB6v\xD4\xC9\xF1\xE8\x14\xAD9\xA9\xC3aq\xE2V#;-\xA0\xE5\xB7mZ#\xB8/\xF3g\x05\xF1\x1F\xB3U\x9E\xF2\xFA\x98\xB7\\\xB0\x81\xF2$\x7F\v\x9A\xD0\x1D\x94\x12\fn\x04\xFD\x91c6\xE4WF_\xCE\xD3$6\xF2Zi5\t\x01\xB5\xB46\\\xB2\xF8J\xC2\xBA\x93p\xAF\x8EF\x042\xBCv\xF1\xB1\xA7\x97\x01\xF5\v@\xEAF\xB6\x9D\xC6\xD9\x11\xEE\xF9\x840\xEC\x8B\xA7\xCE\xE7L\xA6\xB5\xB2\xB0\xD2\xD9\xAD(\a-\xF4\x9F\x0E\x82\x9E~\xFF\x00\xCE\x0E\xEB\xD5\x1E\xEC\xE6\xB8\xFE\xE0G\xC9g\xF4h\x84\x8D\x91\xCE\xE1\xB6\xFA\xA1\xEFk\xEC\xBA\x8C\xAB\xAA\xEDSP\x00\xEE\xA9QI\x03\xDC\x85\x1F\xF3\xC5\xDFg\xE7\xF7\x9A>\xD6\xFC\xB8\xAAZ\xC0\xDBVZ\x06\x00\x1Fd\x10\xC6\x95\x04Y\x84\x92\x90\xE6=D\xCC\xF9\xBD\xBA[u\xBA\xFDF\xAA\xDD-; \xA2d\x958#'\xCB\xC3`\x9F(\xF2'\xA7\xE5\x1E\xD8\xAB\r$\x14\xFB\xBB\x16\x06\xEE76\x00\\\xF9\xF8\xA9\x9F4\x92X\xBD\xC4\xDB\x8B\x9E\x13\xEDO_u\"\xB5\x02|)\xF9\xEB0L\x87=\x8F\r-\x87\xAA\x0E)\x0F\xB5\xCF\x91`\x9ES\xE6W\a\xF3\x1F|E\x1E\x9FG\tk\xA3\x85\xA0\xB6\xF6\xB3F/\xCD\xBC.\x9C\xEA\x89\x9E\bs\xC9\xBF\x99Ir.\xB5g\xED1\x89\"&R\xCEu\xDC\xB9\x12B\x8A\xDD\x8FL\xA8:\xC3kQ\x16*)I\xB5\xEC\x00\xBF^\x06\x1F=\x15-Q\x06\xA2&\xBE\xDCnh6\xF9\x85\x10{\x9A,\xD2Bo\xA7jVl\xA4\xE7O\xED|<\xCBV\x8F\x9A\xBB\xC5;\xF8\xDA&8&oRJT\xAE\xFA\xFB\xAEA \x9B\xF48\x99\xD0\xC4\xE6vnh-\xF0\xB0\xB6<\xB8\\\x0E \xDC\x14\xB78k.{\xD4\x1A34\x8C\xCD\x9C+\x95\xFA[\x12W1\xA8u)\xEE>\xD2\x1FQQS\x81*$\x05\x1D\xEB\xB9\xEB\xE6>\xF8L\x86(\xCD\xD8\xD0\x0F\x90\x01p\x92y)\r\aR3VV\xCB\xB5z\r\x1F1T\xE9\x94Z\xBAvT)\xF1%-\xB6%\xA6\xD6\xB3\xA8\x06\xCB\x16\xE3\x9C5\xF4\xF0\xC8\xF6\xC8\xF6\x02\xE6\xF0H\x04\x8FC\xD18=\xC0X\x1C,\xCDZ\x91\x9A\xB3\xCC*\\<\xC3\x98ju\xB8\xB4\xB6\xBB\x88,\xCF\x94\xB7\x93\x15\xBD\xA9N\xD6\xC2\x89\xDA,\x84\x8B\x0FD\x8Flr\x1Ah)\xCB\x9D\v\x03K\xB9\xB0\x02\xFE\xB6\xE5p\xBD\xCE\x00\x13{'\xCA\x8Fh\rJ\xAB\xC2\x93\x0Ev{\xCC\x12\xE2\xC9c\xC3>\xCB\xD5\x17T\x87\x1A\xB1\e\x14\t\xE56R\xB8\xF98\xAE4\xEA6\xB88B\xD0A\xBF\xE9\x1C\xF8\xFA\xF9\xA9\xBD\xE2n7\x9E-\xC9\xE3\xC3\xD13\xE5\x8DO\xCD\xD9*\x9B*\x9F@\xCC\xB5J4)N%\xD7\xA3\xC1\x96\xB6\x90\xE2\xC5\xAC\xA2\x12y\"\xC3\x9F\x8CO5,\x15\x0Ek\xA6`qo\x17\x00\xDB\xD1F\xC9\x1E\xC0C\x1CE\xD3~j\xCE\x15\xBC\xF1W]S0U\xA6V\xAAKBP\xA9s\x9ES\xAE\x14\xA4Y \xA9\\\xD8a\xD0S\xC3L\xCE\xCE\x06\x06\xB7\xC0\v\x05\xC7\xBD\xF2\x1D\xCF7>i\xA3\x16\x13\x17\xA3\x8E\x94\x97\x9Cq%\x98I,\xC2If\x12K0\x92Y\x84\x92\xCC$\x96a$\xB3\t%\x98I,\xC2I\x7F\xFF\xD9"
```

So the above data should display the above poster. 
But when i add that code

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,**HERE**" />`

The movie poster isnt shown, does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I can see one possible error. The image link you have posted in .jpg while you are setting mime-type as gif. Please check with mime type as image/jpeg.

**EDIT:**

I tried the following sample code, works fine:

```
<%
   require 'open-uri'
   raw_img_data= nil
   open('http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/s2IG9qXfhJYxIttKyroYFBsHwzQ.jpg') do |f| raw_img_data= f.read end
   base_64_img_data= Base64.encode64(raw_img_data)
%>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= base_64_img_data%>" />
```

Did you encode the raw image data to base64 before placing it as part of the URI?

Comment: Oh yeah. No i tried it with jpg aswell, don't know why gif is there though. 
Nevertheless, it still doesnt work with JPG

Comment: BTW this is a binary blob representing JPEG

Comment: But i will fetching the img data via a rake file and then display it in a .html.erb page 

My goal is to find the movie poster BASED on the BLOB data

Comment: Please post code for your rake task. If you are storing it in Database then post code snippets for those as well.

Comment: Try `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= Base64.encode64(@movie.posters.first.data) %>" />`